# JavaScript to create a global radio button for all subsequent radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have this set of labels and radio buttons that look like this:

```
Entertainment: <input type="radio" name="entertainment" id="entertainment" value="0" checked/>
               <input type="radio" name="entertainment" id="entertainment" value="1" /> 
               <input type="radio" name="entertainment" id="entertainment" value="2" /><br />


Radio: <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="0" checked/>
       <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="1" /> 
       <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="2" /><br />

Dancing: <input type="radio" name="dancing" id="dancing" value="0" checked/>
         <input type="radio" name="dancing" id="dancing" value="1" /> 
         <input type="radio" name="dancing" id="dancing" value="2" /><br />

Music: <input type="radio" name="music" id="music" value="0" checked/>
       <input type="radio" name="music" id="music" value="1" /> 
       <input type="radio" name="music" id="music" value="2" /><br />

Television: <input type="radio" name="tv" id="tv" value="0" checked/>
            <input type="radio" name="tv" id="tv" value="1" /> 
            <input type="radio" name="tv" id="tv" value="2" /><br />

Film: <input type="radio" name="film" id="film" value="0" checked/>
      <input type="radio" name="film" id="film" value="1" /> 
      <input type="radio" name="film" id="film" value="2" /><br />

Theatre: <input type="radio" name="theatre" id="theatre" value="0" checked/>
         <input type="radio" name="theatre" id="theatre" value="1" /> 
         <input type="radio" name="theatre" id="theatre" value="2" />
```

The idea is that the three 'Entertainment' radio buttons at the top control all the radio buttons below. A 'global switch', if you will, to save people time. Does anyone know the necessary JavaScript/jQuery to accomplish this? I can't find a correct example online.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You'll want to use `.prop('checked',true)` to switch on the value of a particular radio button. http://api.jquery.com/prop

Comment: A document page can't have same `id` to multiple elements!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(':radio[name=entertainment]').change(function() {
  $(this).nextAll(':radio[value="'+ this.value +'"]').prop('checked', true);
  $(this).nextAll(':radio[value!="'+ this.value +'"]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zkTud/14/)**

#### Note

`id`s should be unique.

Comment: @AzzyDude check my answer and demo, I think you want this